# Handle Promise in Obversable for Angular HTTP Interceptor failes

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, rxjs

I am facing the following sitatuon:

I have an authentication service, base on angular/fire with firebase authentication. The authentication service should return the id token with the idToken observable from angular/fire:

```
public getAuthenticationToken(): Observable<string | null> {
const auth = getAuth()

return idToken(auth).pipe(
  switchMap(token => {
      return of(token)
  })
)}
```

The HTTP Interceptor just should take the token from the authentication service and and add the token to the header if available:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.userService.getAuthenticationToken().pipe(
      switchMap((token) => {
        const newRequest = request.clone()

        if(token) {
          newRequest.headers.set('Authorization', token);
        }
        return next.handle(newRequest)
      })
    )
  }
}
```

So far so good. My problem is, every request, which goes out, will be sendthe first time, but no second time. Every request will be send by a feature service during an effect. If I remove the interceptor, every request works as expected, multiple times.

Here is an example effect:

```
  SaveArticle$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(savedArticlesActions.saveArticle),
      concatMap((payload) =>
        this.articleService.saveArticle(payload).pipe(
          map((response) =>
            savedArticlesActions.saveArticleSuccess({
              article: response.article, message: "Article successfully saved"
            })
          ),
          catchError((error) => of(savedArticlesActions.saveArticleFailure(error)))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

If i change the map operator to switchMap, the requests will be send multiple time with the interceptor. But as soon as i switch to another map operator, the requests still just sended one time and not again.

My setup:

- Angular 16
- RXJS 7.5

I know Im missing a important part but dont know what.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would recommend getting the token once and storing it. It is a bit strange getting the token every time before every request.
And you dont need this part at all 
.pipe(
  switchMap(token => {
      return of(token)
  })

Why you clone the request ? just set its header and pass to next

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the hint. Would make sense to store them in a session cookie. The clone for the request is necessary, because of the request is generally immutable, so we have to create a new instance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `idToken()` is an `Observable` that never completes.

Doing `this.userService.getAuthenticationToken()` in your request means that the observable inside the `concatMap` will never complete, even though you received the first response.

You need to call `first()` in your interceptor to wait only for the first token value.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.userService.getAuthenticationToken().pipe(
      first(),
      switchMap((token) => {
        const newRequest = request.clone()

        if(token) {
          newRequest.headers.set('Authorization', token);
        }
        return next.handle(newRequest)
      })
    )
  }
```

That should ensure that the http call completes and `concatMap` will subscribe to next value.